# Add a region to the page--front.html.twig

Tags: blocks, theming

I've created a few new region in my yml

```
regions:
      header: "Header"
      jumbotron: "Jumbotron"
      chiffres: "Chiffres"
      steps: "Etapes"
      presentation: "Presentation des formules"
      map: "Carte"
      nav: "Navbar"
      content: "Content"
      footer: "Footer"
```

Those regions are displayed in my backend and I can place some block inside.

I've also created a **region--thename.html.twig** for each one of my new regions.

I want to do this in my **page--front.html.twig**

```
    {{ page.header }}

<main class="d-flex flex-column">
    {{ page.jumbotron }}
    {{ page.chiffres }}
    {{ page.presentation }}
    {{ page.steps }}
    {{ page.map }}
</main>

{% if page.footer %}
  {{ page.footer }}
{% endif %}
```

But my regions are showing only if I add a block inside it.

This is my first drupal, so i may have miss  something...

Comment: Not sure you've actually asked a question, what's your issue?

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. Basically, I want to add the content static of my region into my page--front

Comment: Empty regions don't get printed, that's right. I still don't get the question. Can you maybe ask a real question somehow?

Comment: Hmmm... How to display my region--header.html.twig ? I have a <nav> inside it for exemple. Then I need to display the content of my region--chiffres.html.twig (only html inside it)

Comment: The purpose of regions are to dynamically render blocks placed inside them. If you want to render static HTML, write it directly in your `page.html.twig` instead, or use Twig include ´{% include '@mytheme/static.html.twig' %}`.